# error on starting rails server with error to load gem simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am in stuck to install railsinstaller into my windows pc.somebody, please help me.

> path/to/dir/runtime.rb:89:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'simple_form'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
>   Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper

Backtrace for gem load error is:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
_view/helpers.rb:40:in `<module:Helpers>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
_view/helpers.rb:4:in `<module:ActionView>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
_view/helpers.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
_view/base.rb:5:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action
_view/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/simple_form-3.1.0/lib/simpl
e_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb:69:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/simple_form-3.1.0/lib/simpl
e_form.rb:2:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/simple_form-3.1.0/lib/simpl
e_form.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:86:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:81:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:70:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:70:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.
rb:102:in `require'
C:/Sites/todo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mmands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mmands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mmands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mmands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mmands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5
/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5
/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/todo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0
/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you run the generator ```rails generate simple_form:install```?